# Spring versions mix

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm starting a new project using spring and spring-security.

Right now this is the dependencyManagement section of my POM:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</dependencyManagement>
```

Spring security documentation states that:

> Spring Security builds against Spring Framework 4.1.6.RELEASE, but should work with 4.0.x.

So my question is, does anyone know if I can mix these version of spring or if I'm better of downgrading spring-framework to 4.1.6.RELEASE?

Comment: Paste your complete POM.xml, It is possible to specify a Parent, which will have necessary version numbers for a lot of them. This way, you wont need to bother with version numbers, thereby eliminating the problem.

Comment: This is my superpom, but my main question is if It is any known issues with mixing spring-framework 4.2.1.RELEASE with spring-security 4.0.2.RELEASE. I don't have any probblems so far, but who knows?

Comment: Then my answer is you wont have any problems mixing these 2 versions, it should work as its mentioned 4.0X.

Comment: you don't have to downgrade it.. it works.